# Calculating: $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^\sqrt{n} {(1-\frac{x^2}{n})^n}dx$

Tags: sequences-and-series, integration, limits, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prove: $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{\sqrt n}(1-\frac{x^2}{n})^ndx=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91378/prove-lim-limits-n-to-infty-int-0-sqrt-n1-fracx2nndx-int)

I need some help calculating the above limit.

What i have observed so far is that:

1. For all x the limit of the sequence inside the integral as n tends to infinity is $e^{-x^2}$
2. I can use Dini's theorem to show that: $f_n(x) = {(1-\frac{x^2}{n})^n}$ uniformly converges to $e^{-x^2}$
3. Consequently i can use the theorem regarding "the integral of the limit is the limit of integrals" for the function sequence $f_n(x)$ and it's limit function $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$

All this is well and good, but i would be ignoring the fact that the interval integrated upon is [0,$\sqrt{n}$], and so also affected by the limit.

What should i do to resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can apply dominated convergence theorem, since $e^{—x}\geq 1-x$ for each $x\geq 0$ and $e^{-x^2}$ is integrable on $(0,+\infty)$.  Define $g(x)=e^{-x}-(1-x)$. Then $g'(x)=-e^{-x}+1\geq 0$ for $x\geq 0$ hence $g(x)\geq g(0)=0$. Now, we have for $0\leq x\leq \sqrt n$,
$$0\leq \left(1-\frac{x^2}n\right)^n\leq \left(e^{-\frac{x^2}n}\right)^n=e^{-x^2}.$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate on your answer? I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: @JohnnyE. I have added more details.

Comment: Thanks. also apparently this question has been asked before: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91378/prove-lim-limits-n-to-infty-int-0-sqrt-n1-fracx2nndx-int?rq=1

Comment: I am still not clear how to use what you wrote to show that: $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{\sqrt n}(1-\frac{x^2}{n})^ndx=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}dx$ , do you mean to use the sandwich theorem? if so, what do i do about the lower bound?

Comment: No, I meant the dominated convergence theorem (I show that the function we integrate are bounded independently on $n$ by an integrable function).

Answer (score 1):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/383953/practice-preliminary-exam-evaluate-the-limit/383980#383980). Apply the substitution of variables $ y = x^2 $ to your integral gives

$$ \frac{1}{2}\,\int _{0}^{n}\! \left( {\frac {n-y}{n}} \right) ^{n}{\frac {1}{
\sqrt {y}}}{dy} $$

Apply another change of variables $ y=nz $ casts your integral to the beta function

$$ \frac{1}{2}\,\sqrt {n}\int _{0}^{1}\!{\frac { \left( 1-z \right) ^{n}}{\sqrt {
z}}}{dz}
 = \frac{1}{2}\,{\frac {\sqrt {n}\Gamma  \left( n+1 \right) \Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma 
 \left( n+3/2 \right) }}
$$

Taking the limit as $n\rightarrow \infty$ gives $ \frac{1}{2} \Gamma(\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{\pi}{2}\,.$

You can use Stirling's approximation 
    $n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n} \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$  of the $n!=\Gamma(n+1)$ to evaluate the above limit.