# Finding integrating the sequence of functions $f_n(x)=\frac{2nx}{1+n^2x^4}$

Tags: real-analysis

If $f(x)=\lim_{n \to \infty}f_n(x)$ where $f_n(x)=\dfrac{2nx}{1+n^2x^4}$, find
$$\int_0^1f(x)dx\quad \text{and} \quad \lim_{n \to \infty}\int_0^1f_n(x)\,dx$$

For the first part:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)=0$$

Therefore

$$\int_0^1f(x)\,dx=\int_0^10\,dx=0$$

Then for the second part:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_0^1f_n(x)\,dx=\lim_{n\to \infty}2n\int_0^1\frac{x}{1+n^2x^4}\,dx=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(\tan^{-1}(n)-\tan^{-1}(0)\right)=?$$

It looks like it goes to $\pi/2$ since $\tan^{-1}$ is an integer when we're at $\pi/4,5\pi/4,9\pi/4,\ldots$

and these are a distance of $\pi/4$ from $\tan^{-1}(0)$. Then we get $\pi/2$. But I dont see how else to show this or if my calculations are correct. 
Does this make sense? Is there a better way to show this?

Comment: $\tan^{-1}\infty = \pi/2$ and $\tan^{-1} 0 = 0$. Also, the factor 2 in front of the term $\left( \tan^{-1} n - \tan^{-1} 0 \right)$ should be removed. Thus the limit is $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Finally, your calculation completely makes sense, so I'm curious what are you suspecting.

Comment: Oh whoops missed that on the substitution.

Comment: @sos440: I guess an explanation of how you knew what the limit was.

Comment: In your last line with integrals the expression for $\,f_n(x)\,$ is wrong: it must be $\,\int\frac{2nx}{1+n^2x^4}dx\,$ ...

Comment: [Here's a related question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/270664/5531)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int\limits_0^1\frac{2nx}{1+n^2x^4}dx=\int\limits_0^1\frac{d(nx^2)}{1+(nx^2)^2}=\left.\arctan nx^2\right|_0^1=\left(\arctan n-\arctan 0\right)=$$

$$=\arctan n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the substitution $x = y/\sqrt{n}$ to get

$$
\begin{align}
2 \int_0^1 \frac{nx}{1+n^2 x^4}\,dx &= 2 \int_0^\sqrt{n} \frac{y}{1+y^4}\,dy \\
&\to 2 \int_0^\infty \frac{y}{1+y^4}\,dy \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2}.
\end{align}
$$

(The last integral can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/110457/5531).)