# Calculus - limit involving uniform convergence

Tags: calculus

$$
\lim_{n\ \to\ \infty}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{\,n\,}\,}\left(1-{x^{2} \over n}\right)^{n}
\,{\rm d}x 
$$
I have a problem solving this limit...the only thing I was able to do is to prove that the function inside the integral uniformly converges to ${\rm e}^{-x^{2}}$.

Thanks !.

Comment: If you write the integral as $\int_0^\infty \chi_{[0,\,\sqrt{n}]}(x)\cdot \left(1 - \frac{x^2}{n}\right)^n\,dx,$ does that help you?

Comment: Have you tried making a change of variable so the interval of integration is constant?  That is, $y = x/\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: I took your advice and got a new integral that goes from 0 to 1, but i`m not sure how to evaluate it.. I thought to change a variable again y=sin(t) ..is that what you meant ? thanks again..

Answer (score 1):

Define $f_n(x):=\chi_{(0,\sqrt n)}\left(1-\frac{x^2}n\right)^n$. Using the inequality $\log(1-t)\leqslant t$ for non-negative $t$, we get that $f_n(x)\leqslant e^{-x^2/2}$. Here, we have that $f_n\to e^{-x^2}$ uniformly on compact sets, so fix $\varepsilon>0$, and $A$ such that $\int_A^\infty e^{-x^2}\mathrm dx\lt\varepsilon$, then write for $n\gt A^2$, 
$$\left|\int_0^\infty f_n(x)\mathrm dx-\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\mathrm dx\right|\leqslant 2\varepsilon+\int_0^A|f_n(x)-e^{-x^2}|\mathrm dx.$$

Answer (score 1):

A [related problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179623/calculating-lim-n-to-infty-int-0-sqrtn-1-fracx2nndx/179650#179650). Using two changes of variables $y=\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $z=y^2$ in a row puts the integral in the form of the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)

$$ \int_0^ \sqrt{n}  (1-(x^2/n))^n dx = \sqrt{n}\int_{0}^{1}( 1-y^2 )^n dy = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}\int_{0}^{1}z^{-1/2}( 1-z )^n dz  $$

$$ = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{2}\frac{\Gamma(1/2)\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(n+3/2)} .$$

Now, you can use the Stirling approximation

> $$ n!=\Gamma(n+1)=n! \sim \left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\sqrt{2 \pi n}$$

to find the limit. The answer is $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\color{#c00000}{\tt Heuristically}$,

> \begin{align}
> \int_{0}^{\root{n}}\pars{1 - {x^{2} \over n}}^{n}\,\dd x
> &=\int_{0}^{\root{n}}\exp\pars{n\ln\pars{1 - {x^{2} \over n}}}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&\sim\int_{0}^{\root{n}}\exp\pars{n\bracks{-\,{x^{2} \over n}}}\,\dd x
> \sim\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-x^{2}}\,\dd x = \color{#66f}{\large{\root{\pi} \over 2}}
> \end{align}