# Definite integral: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\sqrt n}^{\sqrt n}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2n}\right)^n \,\mathrm dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\sqrt n}^{\sqrt n}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{2n}\right)^n \,\mathrm dx $$

I tried very hard to solve this integral and it looks like while $n$ goes to infinity it will give us a Gaussian distribution (I feel somehow, I mean maybe it is obvious from inside of integral).

Anyway, I tried to split this function inside of integral but it didn't work.

Comment: You don't solve an integral, you compute it!

Comment: Computer the integral first by substituing $\frac{x}{\sqrt(2n)}$ =sin x.

Comment: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179623/calculating-lim-n-to-infty-int-0-sqrtn-1-fracx2nndx) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91378/prove-lim-limits-n-to-infty-int-0-sqrt-n1-fracx2nndx-int) are declared duplicates of each other, but not duplicates of your post. The answers in both however are really good and pertinent here, and so I thought you might enjoy them.

Comment: @ Mercy , @ GTX OC  and @J.W.Perry thank you all for your comments and hints. I read and I solved.(Sorry I computed :). ). Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

One definition of the exponential function is
$$\operatorname{e}^u = \lim_{n\to\infty}\left( 1 + \frac{u}{n} \right)^n $$

In your case $u = -\tfrac{1}{2}x^2$. An appropraite substitution should help you continue.