# Limit using integral: $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int _0^\sqrt n (1-\frac {x^2}n)^ndx$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

**Question:**
Evaluate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int _0^\sqrt n (1-\frac {x^2}n)^ndx$

**Thoughts**
We proved that the inner function uniformly converges to $e^{-x^2}$ in the segment but then calculating the integral made that turns out is something we don't know how to do.
Hints?

Comment: See also: [Prove: $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{\sqrt n}(1-\frac{x^2}{n})^ndx=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/91378)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Write the integral as:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(1-\frac{x^2}{n}\right)^n\chi_{[0,\sqrt{n}]}(x)dx$$
where $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function of $A$ (i.e. it is $1$ on $A$ and $0$ everywhere else). Then use the [dominated convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) to bring the limit inside the integral.

Comment: thx, haven't studied that theorem so I guess we're not allowed to use it... any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If the inner function converges uniformly to a function then the integral converges uniformly, also.  So you just need the probability integral or the properties of the normal distribution function.

Here $$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} dx=\sqrt{\pi} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^\infty e^{ -x^2}dx =\sqrt{\pi}/2.$$

Answer (score 0):

$(1- \dfrac{x^{2}}{n})^{n} \le (e^\frac{-x^{2}}{n})^{n} \le  e^{-x^{2}} $ because $1-u \le e^{-u}$

$ e^{-x^{2}} $ is integrable and $f_{n}(x)= (1- \dfrac{x^{2}}{n})  $ converges $f(x)=  e^{-x^{2}} $ pointwise . By using Dominated Convergence Theorem. so $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow\infty} \int f_{n} d \mu =\int f d\mu $$ then $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow\infty} \int^{\sqrt{n}}_{0} (1- \dfrac{x^{2}}{n}) d x =\int^{\infty}_{0}  e^{-x^{2}}  dx $$ so lets say $$ A= \int^{\infty}_{0}  e^{-x^{2}}  dx  $$ then $$ A^{2}=  \int^{\infty}_{0}  \int^{\infty}_{0}  e^{-(x^{2}+y^{2})}  dx    $$... Ok, I think it is enough , can you continue yourself now ?

Comment: hhh We haven't studied nor Dominated convergence theorem nor Normal distribution integral... Are there any other ways not involving those? :-)